# Is BIGSERIAL transaction safe if running concurrently? (PostgreSQL,libpqxx)

Tags: c++, postgresql

Let's Assume I have the following Tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Game
(
    GameNr         BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    blabla         int --More values
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS player
(
    GameNr         BIGINT references Hand (HandNr),
    FOO            int --More values
);
```

And Following C++ code: 2 Simple INSERT STATEMENTS inside one transactional class.

```
pqxx::connection database_connection("CONNECT TO DATABASE INFORMATION");

database_connection.prepare("Game_Insert", "INSERT INTO Game(blabla)\
        VALUES($1)\
RETURNING gamenr");


database_connection.prepare("player_Insert",INSERT INTO player(GameNr,FOO "\
 VALUES($1, $2)");

pqxx::work work(database_connection);

try
{
        pqxx::result result = work.exec_prepared("Game_Insert",2);

        int64_t game_nr;
        result.at(0).at(0).to(game_nr);

        for(const auto& player: players)
        {       
             result = work.exec_prepared("player_Insert",game_nr,2);
        }


        work.commit();

    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
        work.abort();
    }
```

And now this code is run concurrently many times. What happens to the BIGSERIAL sequence can there be any gaps between the numbers or duplicates?

Googling around gives me confusing answers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about the difference between bigserial and bigint. Bigserial does not actually become a data type, it's a convenience to define the column as a bigint, to create a sequence, and use the sequence for the default value. The data type becones bigint See the create table and table description below.

```
postgres=# create table Games(GameNr bigserial, blabla integer);
    CREATE TABLE
    postgres=# \d+ games
                                                   Table "public.games"
     Column |  Type   |                       Modifiers                        | Storage | Stats target | Description
    --------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
     gamenr | bigint  | not null default nextval('games_gamenr_seq'::regclass) | plain   |              |
     blabla | integer |                                                        | plain   |              |


    postgres=#
```

And there will be gaps at some point, always will be with sequences, but no duplicates.